# Python, opposite function urllib.urlencode

Tags: python, urllib

How can I convert data after processing `urllib.urlencode` to dict?
`urllib.urldecode` does not exist.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) for `urlencode` say,

> The urlparse module provides the
>   functions parse_qs() and parse_qsl()
>   which are used to parse query strings
>   into Python data structures.

(In older Python releases, they were in the `cgi` module).  So, for example:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import urlparse
>>> d = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
>>> s = urllib.urlencode(d)
>>> s
'a=b&c=d'
>>> d1 = urlparse.parse_qs(s)
>>> d1
{'a': ['b'], 'c': ['d']}
```

The obvious difference between the original dictionary `d` and the "round-tripped" one `d1` is that the latter has (single-item, in this case) *lists* as values -- that's because there is no uniqueness guarantee in query strings, and it may be important to your app to know about what multiple values have been given for each key (that is, the lists won't always be single-item ones;-).

As an alternative:

```
>>> sq = urlparse.parse_qsl(s)
>>> sq  
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> dict(sq)
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

you can get a sequence of pairs (urlencode accepts such an argument, too -- in this case it preserves order, while in the dict case there's no order to preserve;-).  If you know there are no duplicate "keys", or don't care if there are, then (as I've shown) you can call `dict` to get a dictionary with non-list values.  In general, however, you do need to consider what you want to do if duplicates *are* present (Python doesn't decide that on your behalf;-).

Comment: Up vote for Python 2, however Python 3 is all in the `urllib` module. See @phobie answer.

Answer (score 24):

[Python 3 version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) based on Alex's answer:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> d = {'a':'x', 'b':'', 'c':'z'}
>>> s = urllib.parse.urlencode(d)
>>> s
'a=x&b=&c=z'
>>> d1 = urllib.parse.parse_qs(s, keep_blank_values=True)
>>> d1
{'a': ['x'], 'b': [''], 'c': ['z']}
```

The alternative:

```
>>> sq = urllib.parse.parse_qsl(s, keep_blank_values=True)
>>> sq
[('a', 'x'), ('b', ''), ('c', 'z')]
>>> dict(sq)
{'a': 'x', 'b': '', 'c': 'z'}
```

parse_qsl is reversible:

```
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode(sq)
'a=x&b=&c=z'
```

Keep possible duplicates in mind, when parsing user-input:

```
>>> s = 'a=x&b=&a=z'
>>> d1 = urllib.parse.parse_qs(s, keep_blank_values=True)
>>> d1
{'a': ['x', 'z'], 'b': ['']}
>>> sq = urllib.parse.parse_qsl(s, keep_blank_values=True)
>>> sq
[('a', 'x'), ('b', ''), ('a', 'z')]
>>> dict(sq)
{'a': 'z', 'b': ''}
```

1. The lists in the `parse_qs` result may have more than one item
2. Calling `dict` on the `parse_qsl` result may hide values

Comment: It is only reversible when the query was parsed using `keep_blank_values=True`.

Answer (score 16):

[`urllib.unquote_plus()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote_plus) does what you want. It replaces %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent and replaces plus signs with spaces.

Example:

```
unquote_plus('/%7Ecandidates/?name=john+connolly')
```

yields

```
'/~candidates/?name=john connolly'.
```

Comment: He said, he wanted a dict. So your answer is wrong.

Comment: yay, this is what I was looking for.