# Inverse operation to Python's urllib.urlencode?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python, opposite function urllib.urlencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542881/python-opposite-function-urllib-urlencode)

I have a url string which is already formatted with key=value pairs and &'s in between, as created by urllib's urlencode function. Is there a standard Python library utility to reverse this process? That is:

Given a string representing a url, return a string containing the base url and a dictionary containing the key-value pairs in the url.

I can cook up a simple solution on my own that does this for reasonable urls, but I imagine weird things can happen with an arbitrary url. So is there a standard library function that does this safely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) does what you want:

```
>>> bits = urlparse.urlparse('http://www.example.com/foo?bar=zoo&a=b')
>>> bits.query
'bar=zoo&a=b'
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(bits.query)
{'a': ['b'], 'bar': ['zoo']}
```