# Message in sqs contains hex value of "=" instaead of ASCII

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have configured event on my bucket, as soon as there is a new object in bucket, it triggers message to as SQS. Key in my bucket looks like

```
'/model/invalid/SourceSystem/20160101/Monthly/SourceSystem/year=2018/month=01/day=02/test.csv'
```

While reading the message from sqs I get the response as

```
'/model/invalid/SourceSystem/20160101/Monthly/SourceSystem/year%3D2018/month%3D01/day%3D02/test.csv
```

As of now I am using python code for replacing `%3D` with `=`, however it doesn't seem to be a correct solution

```
fileLocation = fileLocation.replace('%3D', '=')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is expected and [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html):

> The s3 key provides information about the bucket and object involved in the event. ***Note that the object keyname value is URL encoded***. For example `"red flower.jpg"` becomes `"red+flower.jpg"`.

As for decoding the URL-encoded key, you can use [urllib.unquote_plus](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote_plus):

> Replace `%xx` escapes by their single-character equivalent. *(The `_plus` suffix means that it will also decode `+` into  - s̳p̳a̳c̳e̳ character)*

**Python 2.x**:

```
from urllib import unquote_plus as urldecode
# ...
fileLocation = urldecode(fileLocation)
```

**Python 3.x**:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus as urldecode
# ...
fileLocation = urldecode(fileLocation)
```

Comment: Maybe also point to the proper function for decoding this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542881/python-opposite-function-urllib-urlencode

Comment: @tripleee Good suggestion. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in this way as well

import urllib.parse

fileLocation = '/model/invalid/SourceSystem/20160101/Monthly/SourceSystem/year%3D2018/month%3D01/day%3D02/test.csv'

fileLocation = urllib.parse.unquote(fileLocation)